# how to undo a move to trash operation in java?

Tags: java, desktop

There is a call `java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().moveToTrash(FILE)` that moves a file to trash.

When a file is in the Trash, how would one go about putting the file back to it's original location using java?

Comment: When you have the `File` object, what can you do with it when you moved the file to the trash?

Comment: There is no portable way in Java 11. In Windows you can access CSIDL_BITBUCKET via JNA.

Comment: how about doing this in OSX?

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that on some OS it is nearly impossible to restore a deleted file.

When you talking about Windows filesystems, then with some JNI code you may access the filesystem and reset the delete flag.

Obviously if it is your program that delete files, you may move them into a bin folder, from which you can restore if needed.

Another option could be to write some service that monitors filesystem activity and may copy files into a bin for later restore. Read about [jnotify](https://jnotify.sourceforge.net/index.html).

For various reasons Windows has no concept of a folder that simply corresponds to the Recycle Bin.

Please refer to https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=5080625

The correct way is to use JNI to invoke the Windows SHFileOperation API, setting the FO_DELETE flag in the SHFILEOPSTRUCT structure.